# C++ unordered_map no matching member function for call to 'find'

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to initialize an unordered_map in c++ and then run the find command, it keeps failing with this error and I'm not sure what to do next. This is in leetcode if that helps.

```
string num = "10003";
unordered_map<string,string> mymap = {
            {"0","0"},
            {"1","1"},
            {"6","9"},
            {"8","8"},
            {"9","6"},
        };
        unordered_map<string,string>::const_iterator got;
        for (auto s: num){
            mymap.find(s);
        }
```

```
Line 15: Char 19: error: no matching member function for call to 'find'
            mymap.find(s);
            ~~~~~~^~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/unordered_map.h:920:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to 'const std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>>>>::key_type' (aka 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>') for 1st argument
      find(const key_type& __x)
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/unordered_map.h:924:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to 'const std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>>>>::key_type' (aka 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>') for 1st argument
      find(const key_type& __x) const
      ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Easy fix: `mymap.find(std::string() + s));`

Comment: @selbie simpler: `mymap.find(std::string{s});` or just `mymap.find({s});`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your key type is `std::string`, but you are passing a single `char` to `find()`. `std::string` does not have a [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that accepts *only* a single `char`, hence the error.

There are other ways to construct a `std::string` from a `char`, eg:

```
mymap.find(std::string(1,s));
```

```
mymap.find(std::string(&s,1));
```

```
mymap.find(std::string() + s);
```

```
using std::literals;
mymap.find(""s + s);
```

```
mymap.find({s});
```

Answer (score 0):

`s` is of type char, while your map has key's of type `string`. Change one or the other.